# (Ocaml) Using 'match' to extract list of chars from a list of chars

Tags: ocaml

I have just started to learn ocaml and I find it difficult to extract small list of chars from a bigger list of chars.

**lets say I have:**

```
let list_of_chars = ['#' ; 'a' ; 'b' ; 'c'; ... ; '!' ; '3' ; '4' ; '5' ];;
```

> I have the following knowledge - I know that in the
>   list above I have '#' followed by a '!' in some location further in the list .

I want to extract the lists ['a' ;'b' ;'c' ; ...] and ['3' ; '4' ; '5'] and do something with them,
so I do the following thing:

```
let variable = match list_of_chars with 
| '#'::l1@['!']@l2 -> (*[code to do something with l1 and l2]*)
| _ ->  raise Exception ;;
```

This code doesn't work for me, it's throwing errors. Is there a simple way of doing this?

(specifically for using match)

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the middle of a list is not itself a list. Only the end of a list is a list. One way to look at it is that the very end of a list (`[]`) is a specific value, and it needs to be there to make something a list. An OCaml pattern match doesn't generate a new value, it just picks out parts of a value that already exists. So a pattern match can't pick out a list from the middle of another list. There's no list there to pick out. A pattern match can pick out a list from the *end* of another list, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another answer points out, you can’t use pattern matching for this because pattern matching only lets you use constructors and `@` is not a constructor.

Here is how you might solve your problem

```
let split ~equal ~on list =
  let rec go acc = function
    | [] -> None
    | x::xs -> if equal x on then Some (rev acc, xs) else go (x::acc) xs
  in
  go [] list

let variable = match list_of_chars with
  | '#'::rest ->
    match split rest ~on:'!' ~equal:(Char.equal) with
    | None -> raise Exception 
    | Some (left,right) ->
      ... (* your code here *)
```

I’m now going to hypothesise that you are trying to do some kind of parsing or lexing. I recommend that you do not do it with a list of `char`s. Indeed I think there is almost never a reason to have a list of `char`s in ocaml: a `string` is better for a string (a `chat list` has an overhead of 23x in memory usage) and while one might use chars as a kind of mnemonic enum in C, ocaml has actual enums (aka variant types or sum types) so those should usually be used instead. I guess you might end up with a `chat list` if you are doing something with a trie.

If you are interested in parsing or lexing, you may want to look into:

1. Ocamllex and ocamlyacc
2. Sedlex
3. Angstrom or another parser generator like it
4. One of the regular expression libraries (eg Re, Re2, Pcre (note Re and Re2 are mostly unrelated)
5. Using strings and functions like lsplit2

Answer (score 1):

`@` is an operator, not a valid pattern. Patterns need to be static and can't match a varying number of elements in the middle of a list. But since you know the position of `!` it doesn't need to be dynamic. You can accomplish it just using `::`:

```ml
let variable = match list_of_chars with 
| '#'::a::b::c::'!'::l2 -> let l1 = [a;b;c] in ...
| _ ->  raise Exception ;;
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was misleading .. I actually don't know the position of '!' 
I don't know how long is the list between '#' and '!' 
is there a way to do this?

Comment: Then you can't use pattern matching. You'll have to write code to search through the list. If it was a string instead of a list of characters you could use a regular expression instead.

Comment: Is positions of '#' and '!' consistent? By that I mean, does '#' and '!' always exist and does '#' always come before '!'?

Comment: It might help if you gave a complete before list and the expected answer.

Comment: yes the positions of '#' and '!' are consistent they are definitely there